# Can't find getcwd() function definition in os.py file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I thought that I should be able to see the source code of packages that I import in Python from the Python Standard Library. When I opened the os.py file, I didn't see any definition of getcwd(). Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

`os` imports system dependent functions with

```
from posix import *
```

or

```
from nt import *
```

where `getcwd` is defined as C function.

Comment: I can't find a posix.py file in my python folder. I can find a posixfile.py file there but it does not have getcwd function defined.

Answer (score 0):

The function is implemented as a C function in `/Modules/posixmodule.c`. In particular it's the function `posix_getcwd` and this is passed back to Python as `getcwd`.